# How do browser like Firefox and Chrome handle image resizing in case only content is image itself?

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement a similar behavior that browser like Chrome or Firefox exhibit if navigated to image file.

Here is an example image:

[image]

If I navigate to this picture in Firefox I see a picture and if I hover over it I see a zoom-in cursor.
If I inspect the element I can see that Firefox creates a "dummy" page to display the image.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css>
 <title>Plaza_de_la_República,_Ereván,_Armenia,_2016-10-02,_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg (JPEG Image, 1280&nbsp;×&nbsp;842 pixels) - Scaled (53%)</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" alt="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" class="shrinkToFit" height="450" width="684">
</body>
```

Here is `<img>` element for clarity:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" alt="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" class="shrinkToFit" height="450" width="684">
```

If I click on the image the image is resized. In this case stretched because it is a big picture, a cursor changes to zoom-out. If I inspect the image I see that class has changed.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" alt="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg/1280px-Plaza_de_la_Rep%C3%BAblica%2C_Erev%C3%A1n%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-02%2C_DD_113-114_HDR.jpg" class="overflowingVertical">
```

The class has changed from `shrinkToFit` to `overflowingVertical`.

But how is this done? There is no `onClick()` event. I cannot see any javascript executed? Is there an internal Firefox hack?

Chrome does somethimg similar. So explanation of its method would be welcome also.

Comment: that's native browser behavior, if the image dimensions are bigger than your screen's you get the zoom option.

Comment: @monssef Yes. But this native behavior is implemented via this dummy page (source above) with css styling and something mysterious extra.

Comment: This is something the browser does natively. If you want to emulate this behaviour, write a click handler that changes the cursor, the image properties etc.